# Loading .csv files based on file name in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a large number of csv files which are named sequentially based on date in the same folder.
example name (d_log_yyyymmddhhmmss). All files have the same number of columns and headers and ultimately I am concatanating.

I am loading them using the following which seems to be fast and efficient:. However, this works for limited files and as I have large amounts I want to split them in cells based on the date they include in their name. For example within a month it would create 30 cell arrays with individual files and 30 concatanated files. Any help appreciated.

```
d = uigetdir();
 filePattern = fullfile (d, '*.csv');
 file = dir (filePattern);
Data =cell (1, numel(file));
 for k=1 : numel(file)
     filename = file(k).name;
     fullfilename = fullfile (d, filename);
     Tables {k} = readtable (fullfilename);
     fprintf ('read file %s\n', fullfilename);
     
 end

bigdata = vertcat (Data{:});
```

EDIT

```
    d = uigetdir();
 filePattern = fullfile (d, '*.csv');
 files = dir (filePattern);
 unique_months_list = {};
for i = 1:numel(files)
    file_month = files(i).name(07:12); % yyyymm part
    basefilename = files(i).name;
    fullfilename = fullfile (d, basefilename);
    if ismember(file_month, unique_months_list);
        TablesSep {i} = readtable (fullfilename);
        fprintf ('read file %s\n', fullfilename);
    else unique_months_list {end+1} =file_month;
        fprintf ('read file %s\n', fullfilename);
        TablesOct {i} = readtable (fullfilename);
  %  elseif
       % unique_months_list {end+2} =file_month;
       % disp('new'); % do your thing if another month
        %TablesNov {i} = readtable (fullfilename);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited according to your comment:

```
files = dir('d_log_*');
unique_months_list = {};

for i = 1:numel(files)
    file_month = files(i).name(7:12); % yyyymm part
    
    if ismember(file_month, unique_months_list)
        disp('same'); % do your thing if same month
    else
        unique_months_list {end+1} = file_month;
        disp('new'); % do your thing if another month
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. I am sorry I was not clear enough, I am struggling to write the loop to be incremental to split the data. For example for the above example data would go into the table if they belong to the second month and if not a new file should  be created and each subsequent file should be checked based on that. if it makes sense..

Comment: To my understanding, this part is where you struggle, isn't it?

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it does not seem to categorise properly. I have edited the code in the main post per your suggestion. It does not work if I use a third else. Also even with two if, it grabs the right months but then splits into wrong tables. I do not understand why, that happens. I have tried three files with months 202006, 202006, 202007 but it seems it will categorise the files from June in the second table rather than the first.